# Явная специализация шаблона

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Такой вопрос. Явная специализация для структуры `box`, выдаёт адрес, вместо значения. Где ошибка и почему она вместо значения выводит адрес?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct box 
{
    char maker [40];
    float height;
    float width;
    float length;
    float volume; 
};

template<typename T>
T maxs(T a, T b)
{
    return a > b ? a : b;
} 

template <> box maxs(box b1, box b2) 
{
    return b1.volume > b2.volume? b1 : b2; }

template<typename T>
T maxs(T a, T b);

template <> box maxs(box b1, box b2);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    box *sa = new struct box;
    box *sb = new struct box;
    sa->volume = 19.0;
    sb->volume = 15.0;
    
    cout << "Max volume: " << maxs(sa, sb) << endl;
    delete sb;
    delete sa;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Явная специализация в приведенном примере нигде не задействуется.

Comment: @user7860670, хорошо, как тогда по вашему будет использована явная специализация для моего кода?

Comment: `maxs(box{}, box{})`, при этом вы должны получить ошибку компиляции, так как для класса `box` не задан оператор << для вывода объекта, возвращаемого `maxs`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы передаете указатели на `box`, никакая явная специализация не работает - работает сравнение указателей, результат - указатель, каковой и выводится...

Кстати, если бы вдруг сработало - как вы себе представляете вывод `box` в `cout`? У вас же специализация возвращает сам `box`, а оператора вывода для этого типа в программе нет...

Далее, для функций я бы выбирал не специализацию шаблона, а перегрузку - типа

```
const box& maxs(const box& a, const box& b) { ...
```

P.S. На будущее будьте внимательны, ставя метки. Вы, когда выбирали метку "шаблоны", должны были прочесть

> Для пометки вопросов, имеющих отношение к templates C++, имеется метка `шаблоны C++`! Шаблоны (Шаблоны проектирования, паттерны проектирования, Design Patterns, ) - представляют собой подход к проектированию чего-либо. Не являются готовым решением, а лишь представляют общее описание решения проблемы, которое можно использовать в различных ситуациях. В ООП широко используются 23 паттерна.

Где в вашем вопросе паттерны проектирования?...

Comment: Я так и думал, что в этом причина, но почему-то сомневался, а правильно ли. Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Просьба к минусующему - поясняйте, почему. Если я неверно ответил - надо же указывать ошибку!